# Xdebug Validation failed

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I am trying to get xdebug works for my remote server ( xdebug + PhpStorm + DigitalOcean ) via ssh.

The SSH and server all config ok, but I am not able to pass teh validation test on the debugger configuration. I've try search other posts, but no luck at all. Can anyone guide me way how to update the Server name and how to fix the Debug protocol null issue?

Many thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I do come cross this link https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/creating-a-remote-server-configuration.html  but no luck as well

Comment: In general (no mention of DigitalOcean anywhere here), the Server Name is set in website/webserver options and usually it matches domain name (e.g. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html or https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html -- first 2 links in Google). PhpStorm uses that field to identify what website sends request to select the correct "Server" entry -- `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Servers`

Comment: RE `Debug protocol 'null;` -- see https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_handler